# Scriptaculous autocompleter problem

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, scriptaculous

In Scriptaculous Ajax autocomplter it chooses the first entry by default . how do i stop it from choosing the first option by default??

Comment: what i am using is :
new Ajax.Autocompleter('search_query', 'search_query_auto_complete', '/search.js', {
    method:'get',
    paramName:'search[query]',
    minChars: 2
});

Comment: Unless something else is needed, perhaps you should tick the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **controls.js** of the Scriptaculous library, on line 286: change "this.index = 0;" to "this.index = -1;". That will fix your problem.

It's a pain that there's no option along the lines of { autoSelectFirst: false }. Hopefully in a future release :)

On another note, you might want to have a look at: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

which lets you disable selecting the first option out of the box.